# Learning gcc internals

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I've recently been very interested in compilers and how they work.  Since gcc has it's source available, I figured it would be the best material to study.

The first thing I realized is that it would be pointless to study gcc if I didn't have a basic understand of simple compiler design principles.  I have since been diligently reading the "Dragon Book" which, from what I have seen, is the de facto book on compiler implementation.

None-the-less, reading that book has only furthered my desire to learn about compilers such as gcc.

Additionally, I find it pertinent to say that I do have a intermediate understanding of c/c++ (aka, I'm not trying to study gcc without knowing c).  I am hoping that studying gcc will help me improve upon that as well.

I have downloaded the latest build I could find; however, I get lost when perusing the source code.

What I'm looking for are suggestions on how to proceed.  Is there a similar project, which is not so massive, I could use as a stepping stone to gcc?  Is there a particular module of gcc which one would recommend studying first?  Are there any books which go into gcc's implementation, rather than it's use? Perhaps I should stop whining and just keep reading the source until it clicks?

Any and all feedback will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  If you think I should study a different compiler/interpreter, I would greatly appreciate suggestions as to which ones.

Comment: You should read the dragon book then write your own compiler. It helps tremendously.

Comment: I've heard GCC is a pain to hack. Maybe LLVM would be an alternative?

Comment: 1. You should understand the language completely at an expert level 2. Write your own compiler for a small language first 3. GCC is a mess. There are much better alternatives

Comment: I have been studying the dragon book.  I'll look into writing my own compiler as well though.

I would also like to mentions that I found gcc has documentation on their internals http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/

Comment: Don't expect to learn anything, unless you are proficient in reading and understanding C. GCC is mature code (and very big). There are lots of "tricks" in there that you will probably not understand. Also: given its size, it will be difficult to see the overall picture (multiple target platforms, cross-compilers, bootstrapping: it's all in there ...) . For learning about compiler theory, you should choose a smaller compiler as a study object, IMHO. But you could try...

Comment: @cs_student: You can also read the GCC internals manual on your own system if you've installed the right package. On Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu, you should be able to install `gcc-doc` or something similar. On Red Hat based systems, it seems to be part of the "gcc" package. Type `info gccint` to read the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to look at a very tiny compiler, I would recommend Fabrice Bellard's [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/).

Also worth mentioning, Fabrice Bellard won the obfuscated c code contest with his [Obfuscated Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/otcc/). There's a deobfuscated version as well, and it fits in a [single c file](http://bellard.org/otcc/otccelfn.c).

These should be great if you want something small and manageable to learn from.

Comment: `8c` from plan9 is pretty easy to read, too.

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely look at clang/LLVM. I think the code base is very readable. One very viable option you'd have is to use LLVM as a back end and write your own simple lexer and parser.

Comment: I agree, LLVM is much better for learning/hacking than gcc.  In grad school, compiler course used LLVM for projects.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am a little biased. My compiler project is using LLVM: http://ellcc.org :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to read the book "ruby under a microscope" and practise with ruby core development, before reading gcc's code. But you should need knowledge on ruby programming. It's about ruby internels.

As I know the best book on gcc is "the definitive guide to gcc" [https://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-GCC-Guides-Paperback/dp/1590595858](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595858). Although it is little bit old, I think you should read this.

Answer (score 0):

Passionate about compilers too, I learned a lot from Niklaus Wirth's book `Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs`. One of the last chapters described the Pascal-0 languages, and the previous chapters show how to parse and compile a very minimalistic language. Pascal-0, PL/0 are two-step compilers, they generate p-code, which is 'machine code' for a minimalistic virtual machine (not unlike Java).

[This page describes a PL/0 virtual machine instruction set](http://blackmesatech.com/2011/12/pl0/pl0.xhtml), and, at the very end, links to a PL/0 compiler and other interesting info.

[Niklaus Wirth has always had a knack](http://pascal.hansotten.com/niklaus-wirth/pl0/) for writing readable and well-structured code. Here's the language definition and many other interesting links.

The advantage of studying and using Pascal, is that the language is very structured, and not an evolution from Assembler (like C). It makes compiling much easier. It's not even necessary to do several passes...